# Is this the correct way to ask "Is this your first time on the island XY?"

Tags: english-to-german

I want to ask

> Is this your first time on the island XY?

I translated it like this

> Ist das Ihr erstes Mal an der Insel XY?

Is my declension of the pronouns correct?

Comment: Hi, yes, the original question would be: Is this your first time on the island (called so-and-so)?

Comment: Man sagt auch *auf Insel XY*, ohne Artikel, analog zu den representierten Eigennamen, die meist keinen Artikel tragen, als wäre "Insel" ein Titel wie "Herr", alternativ *zu Herr Meier* oder noch selten *zu dem Herren Meier* , aber immer noch ausschließlich *auf der Insel Ibiza*.

Comment: Verstanden! Danke, vectory!.

Comment: @vectory, das ist völliger Unsinn! Mir fällt nicht ein einziges Beispiel ein, bei dem _auf der Insel XY_ ohne den Artikel gebraucht würde.

Comment: @Kai, I advise you to ignore what vectory wrote in his comment! It is wrong.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich wie meine ? Etwas ist wohl Faul im Staate Dänemark.

Comment: *auf* is used without an article if *Insel* is omitted: *Sind Sie zum ersten Mal auf Sylt?*

Answer (score 5):

> Sind sie zum ersten Mal auf der Insel XY?

Translate *on* to *auf*. *An* would rather be *at*.

Also *zum ersten Mal* sounds a bit more natural. *Jemandes erstes Mal* (like *(ist das) ihr erstes Mal*) rather expresses that you do something, not that you are somewhere. It could be used here (*Ist das ihr erstes Mal auf der Insel?*), but people might think that you are referring not to being on the island, but doing something on the island for the first time (*das* would refer to what you are doing). E. g., imagine you're engaging in an activity XY is famous for and you are asking someone else *Ist das ihr erstes Mal?*. This would be interpreted as asking about the activity, whether they are doing it for the first time (on the island, clearer and much longer would be *Ist das das erste Mal, dass sie auf der Insel XY sind?*)). To add to the confusion, you could still also ask *Machen sie das zum ersten Mal?* (note that then it'd be with *machen*, not *sein*).

Actually, you might even leave out *der Insel* if that's clear, because the island is well-known:

> Sind sie zum ersten Mal auf XY?

---

It's also called *erstes Mal* when someone loses their virginity (*Na, wie war dein erstes Mal?*).

Comment: What's natural depends on dialect, and I wouldn't deem either of the two unnatural, but good catch.

Answer (score 0):

> Bist du zum ersten Mal auf der Insel XY?

would translate as: 
Are you on the island XY for the first time? 
It seems to retain the sense of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself forgetting the propositions in conversations, consider asking more neutral questions like "Sind Sie zum ersten Mal hier?" or "Waren Sie schon mal hier?" depending on what they say.

Answer (score -1):

> **Ist das Ihr erstes Mal auf Ibiza?**
>
> Ist ein Vogel auf dem Berg?

Auch zu beachten:

> auf St. Pauli

da die Kirche St. Pauli auf einem Hügel erbaut wurde.

Sonst aber:

> in Hamburg

Comment: "Ist das ein Bild auf der Wand aufgemalt" und "Ist das ein Bild an der Wand aufgehängt" ergeben keinen Sinn. Meinst du "da" statt "das"? Oder "Ist das ein an der Wand aufgehängtes Bild?"

Comment: @idmean Sinn ergibt es durchaus, nur ist die Syntax etwas entstellt, da die Verben in Klammern für gewöhnlich nicht gesprochen werden, mithin hier nicht zum Satz gehören sondern ergänzende Erklärungen darstellen.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass du im ersten Satz die gefragte Phrase übersetzt, sehe ich irgendwie nicht den roten Faden in dieser Antwort.

Comment: @infinitezero die Übersetzung ist die Antwort. Die weiteren Ausführungen sollen das Idiom  ur festigen und abgrenzen. War sicher nicht an Muttersprachler gerichtet. Der Nebensatz "*da hängen zwei ehemals unterschiedliche Verben vereint*" mag den roten Faden etwas verwirren, ich bin eben selbst darüber gestolpert.